# Local SMTP Server with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, types, smtp

I created a local smtp server using localhost and port 25, I want to be able to create a custom local smtp server and send email using nodemailer. Currently I have this code:

```
const SMTPServer = require('smtp-server').SMTPServer;

const server = new SMTPServer({
  authOptional: true,
  onData(stream, session, callback) {
    let message = '';

    stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
      message += chunk.toString();
    });

    stream.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Received message:');
      console.log(message);
      callback();
    });
  },
  onClose(session) {
    console.log('Connection closed');
  },
});

server.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('SMTP Server Error:', err);
});

server.listen(25, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log('SMTP Server listening on port 25');
  const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');



const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'localhost',  // Replace with your SMTP server address
  port: 25,           // Use the appropriate port
  secure: false,
  tls : { rejectUnauthorized: false }
});

const mailOptions = {
  from: 'myTesteEmail@localhost',
  to: 'myRealEmail@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Test Email',
  text: 'Hello, this is a test email.',
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent:', info.response);
  }
});
});
```

I am getting this message everyTime I try to run de code:

> SMTP Server listening on port 25
> Received message:
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
> From: myTesteEmail@localhost
> To: myRealEmail@gmail.com
> Subject: Test Email
> Message-ID: da0329f7-8b6f-9005-e154-eeff9c62c61e@localhost
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
> Date: Sat, 23 Dec 2023 01:45:02 +0000
> MIME-Version: 1.0
>
> Hello, this is a test email.
>
> Email sent: 250 OK: message queued
> Connection closed

But when I check my email, I got no email from my local smtp. I even tried putting the from email to the same as To email with my real gmail account, but still not working, how can I make this working?

I searched a lot, but I coudln't find any tutorial using a custom local smtp server, they was using an already existing smtp services like mailtril, bravo..

I tried Chat gpt, but no working

Comment: gmail may not like either of the from addresses - have you tried Haraka?

Comment: I have ALSO noticed an absence of ANY tutorial or example of how to setup a custom SMTP server for a new domain.  I simply refuse to believe there are only a few of us that wish to do this and not rely on GMAIL or some other big iron provider.  Almost like we're being steered to these providers intentionally.  I know that sounds paranoid, but I find it weird.  Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77708760/how-to-configure-smtpserver-options-with-pem-key-and-cert