# How to configure SMTPServer options with pem key and cert?

Tags: smtp, nodemailer, lets-encrypt, smtp-auth, smtp-server

The guidance here: https://nodemailer.com/extras/smtp-server/ ... indicated that I should configure my SMTP server (in production) like so:

**Example code from nodemailer site:**

```
const server = new SMTPServer({
  secure: true,
  key: fs.readFileSync("private.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("server.crt"),
});
server.listen(465);
```

**My code:**

```
  environmentSpecificOptions = {
    secure: false,
    disabledCommands: ['AUTH'],
    key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mywebsite.org/privkey.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mywebsite.org/fullchain.pem"),
    name: process.env.SMTP_HOST, // mywebsite.org
    hideSize: false,
}
```

**Current behavior:** Sort of a black box result with no error message.  Here is the output:

```
Message sent: <d3ad5b0e-f355-06a3-b5ac-26118eeaad37@mywebsite.org>
sendResult: {"accepted":["myemail@yahoo.com"],"rejected":[],"envelopeTime":4,"messageTime":44,"messageSize":762,"response":"250 OK: message queued","envelope":{"from":"No_Reply@mywebsite.org","to":["myemail@yahoo.com"]},"messageId":"<d3ad5b0e-f355-06a3-b5ac-26118eeaad37@mywebsite.org>"}
```

**Failure result:** I checked my email and did not receive any message.  Yes, I checked spam and garbage folders as well, 2 days later.

**My question:** Why is this not sending? (variation of title)

**Unrelated musings that may not be pertinent to the main question:** Are most SMTP servers configured to use the cert and private key for the front-end web server?  Because if I do it as I am now, my website users will receive an email from "api.mywebsite.org" instead of "mywebsite.org" which doesn't seem right to me.

**My best guesses:**  Perhaps pem keys need to be handled differently, or perhaps I have to generate my own new key, separate from the website pem key that enables HTTPS?  Or perhaps I should enable secure: true.   Or perhaps I am required to enable authentication when using key & cert?

Comment: Is this about server configuration? Then it's IMHO off-topic here. If it is about programming, a [mcve] would help. But it sounds like you can send ok, just your server doesn't deliver. Also make sure to ask only one question, so either the "why is this not sending" or "how do I change the sender email". That said, check the server logs, probably messages are queued and maybe it tries to deliver. Emails may take a few days till they bounce while the server keeps retrying the delivery. (You did add a valid sender address that can receive bounces, right?)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and for the time you spent analyzing the question, Robert.  Great suggestions in terms of clarifying the question - I have edited it to be more clear.  In terms of the minimal reproducable example, it would be difficult to do one, because the code would need to have a cert (actual registered website).   Due to no response thus far, my plan is to experiment and try to fix myself, and update with my solution.  Thanks again for your time. Merry Christmas as well :)